# Monic polynomial of degree 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions

> Consider a monic polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $5$. The graphs of $f(|x|)$ and $|f(x)|$ are same. If $4$ is a root of $f(x)$, find $f(1)$.

I had some problems while drawing the graph of the function. Can anyone explain the solution?

Comment: Is it $f$ a polynomial or a polynomial function? There is a subtle difference between these two things.

Comment: @Parcly Why did you undo my edit?

Comment: @miracle173 Unnecessary dollar formatting of the 5. Also, any title with MathJax markup won't be considered for hot network questions.

Comment: @Parcly It has already left the hotlist so a correct latex format shouldn't be a problem now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the function attains only positive values for $x > 0$, the root $4$ must be a double root. Since the function is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis, it also must have $-4$ as a double root. The fifth root is therefore invariant under $x \mapsto -x$, hence is $0$. This implies $f(1) = 225$.

Comment: The function is not symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis, but the roots are.

Comment: You're right - I was thinking about | f |.

Comment: Has the question been edited? This doesn't seem to follow from what is written there.

Answer (score 21):

If $x\ge0$ then

- $f(|x|)=f(x)=|f(x)|$, so $f(x)\ge0$
- $f(\left|-x\right|)=f(x)=|f(-x)|$. This, and the fact that $f$ is of odd degree, together imply $f$ is an odd function.

The non-negativity over $\Bbb R^+$, oddness and $f(4)=0$ mean that $+4$ and $-4$ are double roots. Therefore
(since $f$ is monic)
$$f(x)=x(x+4)^2(x-4)^2$$
$$f(1)=225$$

Comment: Since your answer tries to give a complete line of reasoning, +1, you might as well indicate explicitly where you use the hypothesis that $f$ is monic.